# Jquery Draggable is not working in chrome and opera

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have used the `jquery` `ui` dragable on a image in my website, problem is that the functionality is working fine in Firefox but not in chrome and opera. In chrome and opera the dragable is working only for `y axis` and not for `x axis`. The console is totally clean and no error is coming. Here I'm providing my code :

```
$(".withroomimageupper").draggable({
        containment: ".pro_img_big",
        scroll: false,
        axis: "x,y"

});
```

Please help me....

Comment: You seem to have copy pasted some wrong code.. please correct it... or if that is indeed your code then remove the `img").attr("id","dragimage");` line. It does not belong there..

Answer (score 1):

The `axis` is used to constrain the dragging in one of the horizontal or vertical axis.
(*You can only restrict to one of them*)

If you want it to be free just do not pass an axis.

```
$(".withroomimageupper").draggable({
        containment: ".pro_img_big",
        scroll: false
});
```

Comment: I have removed the "axis" part but still it is not working in chrome and opera.

Comment: @user3132101 can you please post http://jsfiddle.net of it so we can see it live..

Answer (score 0):

Please read http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/
Some of the options are not valid.
"axis" option is not needed.

I believe this will work on all browsers:

```
$(".withroomimageupper").draggable({
        containment: ".pro_img_big",
        scroll: false
});
```

Comment: I have removed the "axis" part but still it is not working in chrome and opera.

Comment: Please remove the rest too. Just copy-paste mine (or Gaby) code. If you want to move both in x and y axis remove the axis option.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are adding some lines of code which is not required. I found a Bin sample for you http://jsbin.com/ICEYaZor/2/edit